# Get the category into the url of the product page

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, categories, url

I'm in the middle of learning Craft Commerce.  When I go to an individual product my URL says `/shop/wella-shampoo/`.  I'd like it to say `/shop/**hair-care**/wella-shampoo/` because this is the category this product falls into.

I've tried adding `shop/{categories.first().slug}/{slug}` to the URL Format but I get the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> Craft\Commerce_ProductModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "categories".

Comment: Is `categories` the name of a Category Field Type on your Product Type's Field Layout?

Comment: Hi, no the field is called 'assignToCategory'?

Comment: And does this particular product have variants or no?

Comment: Yes, the product has variants

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing, but since this product type has variants, using this should work:

```
shop/{object.categories.first().slug}/{object.slug}
```

If it didn't have variants, you wouldn't need the `object` reference in front of it.  The same thing applies if you're referencing a field inside of Matrix as well.

This has been made easier in the upcoming Commerce 2 so you don't have to worry about the differences.