# Custom Commerce product type URL from custom field

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

I've run into a dead end when trying to create custom URL's for a product type in Commerce 2. I want to create the URL from a custom field -- a Commerce Product field to be exact. This product does not have variants.

I've referenced [this question here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22497/get-the-category-into-the-url-of-the-product-page), but the example did not work for me.

Here is what I've tried with no success: `{relatedImage.first().id}`, `{relatedImage[0].id}`, `{object.relatedImage.first().id}`.

When the Craft task manager tries to rerun these products, it just errors out (Failed). And I'm not sure where to find task manager error logs to see if I can get any information from them.

Comment: The underlying error for the failed job will be in your project's `craft/storage/logs` or `storage/logs` folder depending on how you have it setup.

Comment: "Could not generate a unique URI based on the URI format". The URI format is: `{relatedImage.first().id}`. It's looking for the id of a selected commerce product. Is that not possible?

Comment: Assuming `relatedImage` is the Commerce Product field, is it inside of Matrix or SuperTable or the like? Or is it at the root?

Comment: It's at the root.

Comment: Just did a test of this locally on the latest Commerce 2 beta. Created a Commerce Products field, added it to the Product Type field layout using `{relatedImage.first().id}` as the URI Format, created a new Product, selected a related Product with an ID of 10, then the new Product's resulting URI is the expected `site.com/10`

Comment: Just to confirm: I have two product types: Images, Recipes. When adding a Recipe, that's where the relatedImage field is present. This field allows me to select an Image-type product. Upon doing so, I want to use that Image's ID as the slug in the URL of the recipe. `{relatedImage.first().id}` does not appear to be working on my end, despite the good results you have found, Brad.